# Web-Scraping using R - I want to extract some table like data from a website

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

I'm having some problems scraping data from a website. I do have not a lot of experience with web-scraping. My intended plan is to scrape some data using R from the following website: https://www.fatf-gafi.org/countries/

More precisely, I want to extract the list of Countries with some sort of sanctions

```
library(XML)
  url <- paste0("https://www.fatf-gafi.org/countries/")
  source <- readLines(url, encoding = "UTF-8")
  parsed_doc <- htmlParse(source, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

But this doesn't bring up the intended information because is not under a table but it is a nested div.

Comment: Table on that particular site is rendered with javascrtipt and you might need to check RSelenium and/or V8 packages to make it work. Though all the table data seems to be stored in `country-data-multi-lang.js` (check developer tools in your web browser).

Comment: @margusl you are right about the js file. It is possible (though not easy) to read the information into R without having to use RSelenium or V8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to test how JavaScript evaluation works with V8, *Embedded JavaScript and WebAssembly Engine*.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/V8/vignettes/v8_intro.html

Create context engine, evaluate requested JavaScript and get the value of `countries` variable from V8 (it's turned into nested dataframe, thus the `unnest()` ),  last row is filled with `NA`s, thus the filter.

```r
library(httr)
library(V8)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
url <- paste0('https://www.fatf-gafi.org/media/fatf/fatfv20/',
              'js/country-data-multi-lang.js')
js_content <- content(GET(url), 'text')

ct <- v8()
ct$eval(js_content)
ct$get("countries") %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(groups)) %>%
  select(c(1:2,4:14,16)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(name))

#> # A tibble: 209 × 14
#>    name       code  FATF  APG   CFATF EAG   ESAAMLG GABAC GAFILAT GIABA MENAFATF
#>    <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>   
#>  1 Afghanist… AF    ""    "mbr" ""    "obs" ""      ""    ""      ""    ""      
#>  2 Albania    AL    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""      ""    ""      ""    ""      
#>  3 Algeria    DZ    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""      ""    ""      ""    "mbr"   
#>  4 Andorra    AD    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""      ""    ""      ""    ""      
#>  5 Angola     AO    ""    ""    ""    ""    "mbr"   ""    ""      ""    ""      
#>  6 Anguilla   AI    ""    ""    "mbr" ""    ""      ""    ""      ""    ""      
#>  7 Antigua a… AG    ""    ""    "mbr" ""    ""      ""    ""      ""    ""      
#>  8 Argentina  AR    "mbr" "non" "non" "non" "non"   ""    "mbr"   "non" "non"   
#>  9 Armenia    AM    ""    ""    ""    "obs" ""      ""    ""      ""    ""      
#> 10 Aruba Kin… AW    "els" ""    "mbr" ""    ""      ""    ""      ""    ""      
#> # … with 200 more rows, and 3 more variables: MONEYVAL <chr>,
#> #   jurisdiction <chr>, id <chr>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky parsing job. The information you need is not in the html you are getting from `readLines`. Instead, it is loaded dynamically by the page using an XHR request. Often, an XHR request like this will return a json string, but in your case it returns javascript where the information is stored as a variable containing an array of json snippets, one for each country. This can be accessed through some string manipulation and json parsing to get your end result:

```r
library(httr)
library(rvest)

url <- paste0('https://www.fatf-gafi.org/media/fatf/fatfv20/',
              'js/country-data-multi-lang.js')
js <- content(GET(url), 'text')

vars <- strsplit(js, 'var countries = ')[[1]][2]
vars <- paste0("{", sub("^\\[\\{", "", strsplit(vars, '\\},\\{')[[1]]), "}")
countries <- do.call(rbind, lapply(vars[1:209], 
                      function(x) as.data.frame(jsonlite::parse_json(x))))
countries <- countries[c(1, 4:13)]
names(countries) <- sub('^.*\\.', '', names(countries))

dplyr::tibble(countries)
#> # A tibble: 209 x 11
#>   name     FATF  APG   CFATF EAG   ESAAMLG GABAC GAFILAT GIABA MENAFATF MONEYVAL
#>   <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 Afghani~ ""    "mbr" ""    "obs" ""      ""    ""      ""    ""       ""      
#> 2 Albania  ""    ""    ""    ""    ""      ""    ""      ""    ""       "mbr"   
#> 3 Algeria  ""    ""    ""    ""    ""      ""    ""      ""    "mbr"    ""      
#> 4 Andorra  ""    ""    ""    ""    ""      ""    ""      ""    ""       "mbr"   
#> 5 Angola   ""    ""    ""    ""    "mbr"   ""    ""      ""    ""       ""      
#> 6 Anguilla ""    ""    "mbr" ""    ""      ""    ""      ""    ""       ""      
#> 7 Antigua~ ""    ""    "mbr" ""    ""      ""    ""      ""    ""       ""      
#> 8 Argenti~ "mbr" "non" "non" "non" "non"   ""    "mbr"   "non" "non"    "non"   
#> 9 Armenia  ""    ""    ""    "obs" ""      ""    ""      ""    ""       "mbr"   
#> 10 Aruba K~ "els" ""    "mbr" ""    ""      ""    ""      ""    ""       ""      
#> # ... with 199 more rows
```